# Is there a way to handle a http post request in a console application?

Tags: c#, http-post, console-application

I'm using c#. I tried httplistener and it works. If I send a post from fiddler, my console receives the data. However, If I try posting from a remote server or use any online tool, it fails. My goal is for the console app to run and listen for any data that will be sent by a third party's server.

Here is how I am setting up the socket:

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("localhost:12345/");
```

Comment: What IP address are you binding against?

Comment: Here is the code that I'm trying out -

Comment: Can you add more details instead of just code? What have you tried? Did you identified the problem? Also please read [mcve]

Comment: listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:12345/");

Comment: I edited it for you; please make sure all applicable information is in the question itself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a socket you provide both an IP address and a port. When you connect to a socket, you have to provide the IP and port **that it is listening on**.

So binding to `localhost` works great when the client program is running on the same device; but doesn't work at all when it is somewhere else. You need to bind to your external IP (bining "what is my ip" seems to work pretty well); or bind to *all* addresses by using `0.0.0.0`; some libraries (including C#) will let you just use `*` for the IP address as well.

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("*:12345/");
```

Comment: I just tried it using hurl.it. I am no longer getting an "Internal Sever Error". The request is getting timed out. I'll post my code in the answer section since I'm unable to edit the question. Thanks

Comment: var listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:63703/");
            Console.WriteLine("HttpProcessor has started and accepted connections...........");
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext contextData = listener.GetContext();
                var rdr = new StreamReader(contextData.Request.InputStream, contextData.Request.ContentEncoding);
                string stringData = rdr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Data from httpRequest: {0}", stringData);
            }

Comment: @user3299927 You can always edit your question.... Can't help you on timeouts; check your firewall?

Comment: It's turned off.  Thank you, I really appreciate the help. I'll keep on researching.